# Prism for converting to a Bounded Integral

Tags: haskell, haskell-lens, bounded-types

I needed a Prism for converting an `Integral a => a` to an `(Integral b, Bounded b) => b`, ensuring that the `a` actually fits into the type of `b`.
My current definition (below) requires the use of `ScopedTypeVariables` and is quite verbose.

I would like to know if there is a better (ideally already defined, and I missed it) way to check if a number fits into a `Bounded` type, or a function for *safe* conversion, that I can use to build the prism.

The current definition:

```
boundedInt :: forall a b. (Integral a, Integral b, Bounded b) => Prism' a b
boundedInt = prism fromIntegral f where
  f n =
    if n >= fromIntegral (minBound :: b) && n <= fromIntegral (maxBound :: b)
    then Right (fromIntegral n)
    else Left n
```

Answer (score 2):

A slightly unsatisfying answer: I don't think there's a library that'll help you here.

Really, you'd need something like

```
safeIntegerToBoundedIntegral :: (Integral b, Bounded b) => Integer -> Maybe b
safeIntegerToBoundedIntegral = boundedFromInteger (minBound, maxBound)

-- helper function's signature lets you avoid `ScopedTypeVariables`
boundedFromInteger :: Integral b => (b,b) -> Integer -> Maybe b
boundedFromInteger (lo,hi) n | toInteger lo <= n && n <= toInteger hi = Just (fromInteger n)
boundedFromInteger _ _ = Nothing
```

which I don't currently see on hoogle or hayoo, then you'd be able to express it a little more easily:

```
integerAsIntegral :: Integral a => Iso' Integer a
integerAsIntegral = iso fromInteger toInteger

integerAsBoundedIntegral :: (Integral a, Bounded a) => Prism' Integer a
integerAsBoundedIntegral = prism toInteger $ \n -> 
  maybe (Left n) Right $ safeIntegerToBoundedIntegral n

integralAsBoundedIntegral :: (Integral a, Integral b, Bounded b) => Prism' a b
integralAsBoundedIntegral = from integerAsIntegral . integerAsBoundedIntegral
```

I split this up the way that I did because I don't know of any guarantee that `fromIntegral` is order-preserving; 
that is, that `a < b` ⇒ `fromIntegral a < fromIntegral b`, and so I settled on using `Integer` as the canonical order
when comparing `Integral`s so it'd at least be consistent.

Answer (score 2):

I think the most direct question is not "Is the number in bounds?" but "Can the number go round trip?" So I'd drop the `Bounded` question altogether:

```
narrowIntegral :: (Integral a, Integral b) => Prism' a b
narrowIntegral = prism fromIntegral f where
  f n | fromIntegral candidate == n = Right candidate
      | otherwise = Left n
      where candidate = fromIntegral n
```

The only trouble is that you could potentially hit an `Integral` type whose `fromInteger` function is partial. You could try checking bounds in that case, but it might be more fun to go a bit wild with something like this:

```
narrowIntegral :: (Integral a, NFData a, Integral b, NFData b) => Prism' a b
narrowIntegral = prism fromIntegral f where
  f n = n `deepseq` unsafePerformIO (narrow n)

narrow :: (Integral a, Integral b, NFData b) => a -> IO (Either a b)
narrow n = (evaluate . force) (narrow' n) `catches`
             [Handler (\(_ :: ArithException) -> return (Left n))
             ,Handler (\(_ :: PatternMatchFail) -> return (Left n))
             ,Handler (\(_ :: ErrorCall) -> return (Left n))]

narrow' n
  | fromIntegral candidate == n = Right candidate
  | otherwise = Left n
  where candidate = fromIntegral n
```